# modal not accepting link id

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have an modal to link a product with a customer and the product discount calculations.
The customer is selected automatically using the modal id, and the product is selected with an select options with a while loop.

The problem is when i use the modal id as so (`id="SetProductCustomer <?=$row["id"];>"`) the script to call the values does not work .where as it should.

The customer select is manual to make it work as i need it to be automatically by just echo it from the modal id (`id="SetProductCustomer<?=$row["id"];>"`).

How i call the modal with a button:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#SetProductCustomer"><li class="t-dropdown-item">Link to Product</li></a>
```

The modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="SetProductCustomer" class="" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-  labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"> <div class="modal-content">
 <a href="view_clients.php"><span class="close">&times;</span></a>
  <h4>Link Product to Customer</h4>
     <div class="item">
         <label style="font-weight: 600; color: blue; font-size: 15px;">Customer:</label>
      <select name="" id="customer_id" >
      <option value="text" name=""  disabled selected>Click to See Customer</option>
<?php
$recordsa = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM addclient");
while($dataa = mysqli_fetch_array($recordsa)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$dataa['company'].'" data-id="' . $dataa['id'].'" >' . $dataa['company'] . '</option>'; //*** Display company name on modal ***
}
?> 
      </select>

          <input type="text" name="customer" id="id" hidden="" />  <!--*** Customer ID ***-->
        
       <br>
        </div> 
        <div class="item">
         <label style="font-weight: 600; color: blue; font-size: 15px;">Product:</label>
          <select name="product" id="product_info" >
                <option value="text" name="product"  disabled selected>Select Prosduct</option>

<?php
$records = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM addproducts");    //*** Select product name ***
while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($records)) {                                             
    // Add profit value and %
    echo '<option value="'.$data['name'] .
                        '"data-description="' . 
                        $data['description'].
                        '"data-price_rate="' . 
                        (   ($data['price_rate'] + 
                            ($data['price_rate']*       
                             $data['percent_profit']/100  )
                            )
                        ) + $data['cost'] ).
                            '" data-cost="' . $data['cost'].'"
                            data-percent_profit="' . 
                            $data['percent_profit'].'" >' 
                            . $data['name'] . 
            '</option>';
}
?>
            </select>
            <div class="item"> <br>
                <label style="font-weight: 600; color: blue; font-size: 15px;">Percent Discount %:</label>
                <label>*Example: 10 *</label>
                <input type="text" name="percent_discount" id="percent_discount" value="0" placeholder="Percent Discount %"  /><br>
                <label style="font-weight: 600; color: blue; font-size: 15px;">* OR *</label><br>
                <label style="font-weight: 600; color: blue; font-size: 15px;">Value Discount R: </label>
                <label>*Example: 10 *</label>
                <input type="text" name="value_discount" id="value_discount" value="0" placeholder="value Discount R"  /><br>
        
                <input type="text" name="price_rate" id="price_rate" placeholder="For testing= price rate" hidden/>                     <!--*** price rate of product save to table= customer_product ***-->
                <input type="text" name="description"  id="description" placeholder="For testing= description"hidden/>                 <!--*** desription of product save to table= customer_product ***-->
                <input type="text" name="profit"  id="cost" placeholder="For testing= profit R" hidden/>
                <input type="text" name="profitPercent"  id="percent_profit" placeholder="For testing= profitPercent" hidden/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="button_container" style="margin-top: 20px;">
            <div class="item">
                <a href="view_clients.php" class="btn btn-success">Cancel</a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="CusProSave">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>       
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Javascript for product calulations and input:

```
<script>
var mySelect = document.getElementById("customer_id");
      
mySelect.addEventListener("change", function() {
    var myOptionTwo = mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-id");
        document.getElementById('id').value = myOptionTwo;
});
       
var mySelectTwo = document.getElementById("product_info");
mySelectTwo.addEventListener("change", function() {
    var myNewOption = mySelectTwo.options[mySelectTwo.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-price_rate");
    document.getElementById('price_rate').value = myNewOption;
            
    var myNewOption = mySelectTwo.options[mySelectTwo.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-description");
    document.getElementById('description').value = myNewOption;

    var myNewOption = mySelectTwo.options[mySelectTwo.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-cost");
    document.getElementById('cost').value = myNewOption;

    var myNewOption = mySelectTwo.options[mySelectTwo.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-percent_profit");
    document.getElementById('percent_profit').value = myNewOption;
});
</script>
```

Comment: How have you tried to get the customer ID from the `id="SetProductCustomer X"` attrubute?

Comment: Yes, that is the main problem. When i get the ID from id="SetProductCustomer " the Script retrieving the values from the product select does not work.

Comment: Not the solution you are looking for... *but* the `data-price_rate` attribute value is missing an open paren `(`. Here --> `(($data['price_rate'] + ($data['price_rate'] * $data['percent_profit']/100))) + $data['cost'])`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a better option... *(See better options below.)*

One problem with this is, space is NOT a valid `id` attribute value character. So use a [valid `id` name character](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id) to deliminate the id name and customer id, such as underscore `"_"`. *(However, see better options below.)*

To assign the customer id portion of your modal id value, use [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element/querySelector) [`attribute selectors`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to get the modal id that starts with `^=` the modal id name, then `split()` the id by some (valid id name character) delimiter, such as and underscore `"_"`

```js
// ASSIGN CUSTOMER ID PART OF MODAL ID TO FORM ID INPUT

// 1) get modal id value, 
let modalid = document.querySelector('[id^="SetProductCustomer_"]').id;

// 2) split it by "_", 
let modalid_arr = modalid.split("_");

// 3) get second element in resulting split array
let custid = modalid_arr[1];

// 4) assign it to customer id form element
document.querySelector("#id").value = custid;

// all together
//document.querySelector("#id").value = document.querySelector('[id^="SetProductCustomer_"]').id.split("_")[1];
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="SetProductCustomer_43" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="item">
      <label style="font-weight: 600; color: blue; font-size: 15px;">Customer:</label>
      <input type="text" name="customer" id="id" />
      <!--*** Customer ID ***-->
      <!-- USING TEXT INPUT FOR DEMONSTRATION PURPOSE  -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**...better options below.**

Put the customer id in a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

```
<div class="modal fade" id="SetProductCustomer" data-customer_id="<?=$row["id"];?>">
  <!-- ... -->

<script>
document.querySelector("#id").value 
  = document.querySelector("#SetProductCustomer").dataset.customer_id;
</script>
```

Or simply put it directly in the customer id form input when processing PHP on the server...

```
<input type="text" name="customer" id="id" hidden="" value="<?=$row["id"];?>" />
```

...and make your code simpler, have one less place things can go wrong, and save your users an extra Javascript execution in their browser.